# Is there a way to find out how many times a stored procedure was invoked since last DB start

Tags: stored-procedures, sybase, count

I am currently in a fairly mismanaged environment, where stored procs were introduced to the database over a few years and some versions became obsolete. Is there an easy way to figure out (preferably in Sybase) how many times a give stored proc was invoked so that we can gain some confidence in removing procs .that were never called recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sybase doesn't store execution counts for stored procedures, but you can use [Sybase Central's activity monitors](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-asarc/asg1150e/mngmonas/@ebt-link;pt=22224;lang=de?target=%25N%15_22394_START_RESTART_N%25) to track SP usage (but only from when you start the session). If you don't like Sybase Central, the other option is to add a line to each SP that increments a counter (i.e. create a table to keep track).

Answer (score 2):

If you can take the hit on performance, enable tracing for a "typical" session (`set tracefile "/some/path/" for some_spid`), and using `set show_sqltext on` you can see all the SQL executed. Then you will need to parse the output looking for stored procedures. Of course this approach cannot give you 100% confidence (e.g. maybe you have a batch job that runs once per year) but it's a start.

Answer (score 1):

Sybase ASE MDA table monCachedProcedures

- This MDA table keeps the ExecutionCount for each stored procedure with a query plan in the Procedure Cache
- You can write a sproc to query this MDA table to take a sample of ExecutionCounts of all stored procedures with query plans in the Procedure Cache
- If you take samples regularly especially near peak workloads over a period of days, week, months, quarters... you will get a reasonably accurate picture of what DBs/sprocs are being used frequently (see example below)

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you please share the source of the sp__snap ?